# Question closed due to being marked as duplicate, but I attest it is not

Tags: discussion, support

I asked this question:

[Salesforce email says I'm connecting via TLS 1.0 but that protocol does not appear in login history](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167029/salesforce-email-says-im-connecting-via-tls-1-0-but-login-history-shows-i-am-no)

This question is unique as it asks specifically about the contradictory email and how I should proceed with it or ignore it. I think this question has a lot of value since others may be facing this same issue, that is their logs show all clients are connecting with TLS 1.2 but Salesforce is sending email to the contrary.

It is clearly (to me at least) not a duplicate of this question, which others have marked it as:

[How to be sure API calls are using TLS 1.2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167027/how-to-be-sure-api-calls-are-using-tls-1-2)

This question asks how I can be sure that a .Net app is calling the site via TLS 1.2. What more can I say in my question to show it is not a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

I tend to agree with you here. The first answer says check the login history. Your second question says you checked the login history and it tells you you're in the clear. But still, you got an email identifying you as a potential problem. I've reopened your question and asked for a bit more relevant detail. Hopefully it doesn't ruffle too many feathers that I reopened almost unilaterally...but usually I'm one of the most aggressive around about closing dupes.

Comment: Thanks for reopening my question and making the edits.

Comment: No problem! Trying to make it a bit more clear what's different, exactly.